# How to find relevant article

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

I'm creating iOS app what suppose to find for user relevant articles. In application I have embedded database what contains quite big amount of articles. When user will put the phrase into search bar App suppose to find best matching articles. Are there any search techniques (except of plain "like %" queries) what would allow me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better way!  Create an entity called `Tags` that has a many-to-many relationship to Article.  When an Article is created or changed parse it to find all the relevant tags for the article.  Then create the tags if they don't already exist and setup the relationships.  When you do a search, search the `tags` not the articles.  Then get the articles from the relationship.  This method can be orders of magnitude faster then searching through plain text on each `Article` entity.  Also for the `Tags` set the field with the keyword to be `indexed` in your model.